# ASP response is cut

Tags: iis, iis-7, asp-classic

I've migrated a classic ASP website to IIS 7. One of the pages used to issue a 7MB long HTML on the old IIS6 site. Now the response is 2.7 MB, and it looks as if the beginning of the response has been cut off. The response starts in the middle of HTML.

I have increased Max bandwidth in site properties to 10 MB.

Buffering is turned on in the beginning of the page, if that matters.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: just to check if it is a buffering issue - i assume the page is doing a loop of some sorts, have you tried doing a response.flush on every iteration of the loop?

Comment: from docs online, IIS7 has a default buffer limit of 4MB for ASP. Pls check if there is a chance that the buffer is cleared and written over after 4 MB. I am not sure if this is even possible, but if this is the case, the math (original 7MB - 4MB Limit) ~ 2.7 MB works out ....

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue, documented along with workarounds here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/925764